# Why am I getting error: `found a tab character that violate indentation` in my Netplan YAML file?

Tags: networking, xubuntu, sudo, netplan

I am getting the following error when trying to do `sudo netplan apply`:

```
Invalid YAML at //etc/netplan/lan-segment.yaml line 11 column 0: found a tab character that violate indentation
```

This happened after modifying a copy of the original file to set a static IP to the Network adaptor as follows:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        ens33:
            addresses: []
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
        ens38:
            addresses: [10.0.0.200/24]
            dhcp4: false
    version: 2
```

[Screen shot of YAML config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZd0b.png)

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of Netplan YAML files are very particular. You're not allowed to use `tab` characters. Instead, you have to use `space` characters only. So your error indicates that there is a `tab` on line 11.

I think your screen grab showing your YAML file is cut off at the top. But line 11 looks like it's probably the line with `version: 2`. So that's probably where the error is. So check line 11. Make sure you don't have any `tab` characters and you're only using `space` characters.

Here's a link to the [YAML Configuration](https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/netplan-yaml/).